# Gradle build error resolving dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to run the SonarQube (version 5.6.6) Scanner for Gradle but am running in to the build error below:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':materialdesignlibrary'.
>     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration  ':materialdesignlibrary:classpath'.
>     Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3.
>            Searched in the following locations:
>                `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom`
>                `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.jar`
>            Required by:
>                project :materialdesignlibrary
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 13.587 secs

Currently having Gradle version 3.3, tried 4.1 as well. Both of which should work according to https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html. I have also tried to edit the `File/Project Structure/Project` Gradle version manually without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project references gradle build tools for android in version 2.3.3, whereas the latest available version is 2.3.0.

Fix the reference to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3` in `:materialdesignlibrary`, which is referenced in `:app:_debugApk`.

Comment: Thanks, this gave me progress (even though I ran into another issue). The weird part is that Android Studio prompts me to upgrade to 2.3.3.